# Convert a kwic to a cvs or a similar format in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

i have a kwic data frame for a paper i write, so i have to copy paste the results in Word e.g. so is there a solution to do this? Which export option do i have?

Comment: I figured it out :) 
firstly i exported it in txt format, then I opened it in Numbers (Mac) and then copied it in Pages. :D 
Thanks!

Comment: officer package.

Answer (score 0):

objects from a `kwic` analsis are just `data.frames` with extra attributes. You can convert them to a regular `data.frame` and then export them to word. I recommend `flextable` for that since the tables look pretty nice and are editable in word directly:

```
library(quanteda)
library(flextable)

txt <- c(text1 = "this is an example sentence with",
         text2 = "this is another example with words in a string")

example_kwic <- kwic(txt, pattern = "example", window = 3, valuetype = "fixed")

pretty_table <- example_kwic %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  autofit()

pretty_table
```

[image]

If you have Word installed, you can export this directly as far as I understand:

```
print(pretty_table, preview = "docx")
```

Or you just use the code snippet above in a RMarkdown document, which is what I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generate output from R to a Word document is with RMarkdown, where the output from an Rmd script can be written directly to a Microsoft Word document.

Since one can create tables with the `knitr::kable()` function, the Word document can also include tables.

Here is an RStudio walkthrough and Rmd script illustrating the technique.

First, in RStudio, create a new RMarkdown document by selecting the new document icon below the menu bar.

[image]

In the popup window that appears next, create a file name and save the file.

[image]

Replace the sample code from the RMarkdown document with the following to load `quanteda` and `knitr` packages, create a `kwic()` object, and print it in a table with `kable()`.

````
## Sample Level 2 Heading

Use the example from `quanteda::kwic()` help to generate to a table that is output to Microsoft Word, via the `kable()` function. 

```{r kwic}
# so answer to 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431078/convert-a-kwic-to-a-cvs-or-a-similar-format-in-r

library(quanteda)
library(knitr)

# use kwic example from quanteda help
kable(head(kwic(data_corpus_inaugural, pattern = "secure*", window = 3, valuetype = "glob")))
```

Here is some text after the `kable()` table.
````

Generate the Word document by selecting the `knit` button from the list of icons in the text editor pane of RStudio, using the `Knit to Word` selection.

[image]

When finished, RStudio opens Word, and the output table looks like this.

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfHzJ.png)

One can use additional features of `kable()` or `kableExtra()` to customize the look of the output table.

Furthermore, another benefit of this approach is that an entire paper or article can be written using RMarkdown, making the analysis completely reproducible. For an example of an entire analysis done in RMarkdown, one can review my commentary on [ToothGrowth Analysis: Full Factorial ANOVA](https://rpubs.com/lgreski/toothgrowthanova) that I published in 2015 to support the Johns Hopkins University Statistical Inference course on Coursera.